# Load data using boost::serialization from untrusted source

Tags: c++, security, boost, communication

I have communication between two parties, where one does not trust the other. I wish to know whether the data I've received is valid before deserializing it, and that it cannot be used maliciously (Cause segfault or major security flaws).

Can boost provide this safety measures, and be safe to serialize?
If boost doesn't provide this kind of security, which serialization does?